# SQL relational database advantages?

Tags: sql, relational-database

I know the concept of relational database and why it is necesary and I agree. I know what is foreign key and everything. But my question is what are the adventages? I mean when I create the relation diagram it does nothing. It doesn't add foreign key automaticly. It doesn't provide a specific select command including both main dable and relatet table. Or at least I couldn't figure it out. Can someone explain it, please?

Comment: Advantages "Maintaining Relationship between tables"

Comment: I do not understand the question. In my opinion relational database is the possibility to use joins in SQL requests. Even if you do not have any foreign keys the database is still relational. MySQL has foreign keys only from version 3.23.44 but it does not mean it was not relational before that version.

Comment: I am seeking an example of what it does, actually. Everyone says basically "it's cool", so to speak. Just one example is enough.

Comment: As far as I understand one of the reasons to use foreign keys is that the rows are deleted when the corresponding row in the main table is deleted. It makes database clean.

Comment: @keiv.fly  Thank you very much. I literally couldn't find an example like that. That's what I was asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Too much to mention really - a search on one of the search engines is the only real way - if you REALLY want to know.  The below highlights:

The many advantages of relational databases can easily be summed into one major advantage: relational databases are dynamic. If you compare a relational database to a flat file database, which is a static data table, you will instantly see the advantage to the former. The ability to bring connections within a database to the surface makes the data within even more valuable.

Some additional links that my benefit:

http://www.ehow.com/list_5985480_benefits-relational-database_.html
http://benefitof.net/benefits-of-relational-databases/

I also forgot to note that a "SQL" database, means that you are also then subject to some for of standards ANSI SQL, so you know that a vast majority of what you learn (or are going to) can be applied to many other SQL (compatible) databases.  I big reason to go that way.